# How should I model the database for this problem? And which ORM can handle it?

Tags: database-design, orm

I need to build some sort of a custom CMS for a client of ours. These are some of the functional requirements:

- Must be able to manage the list of **Pages** in the site
- Each **Page** can contain a number of **ColumnGroups**
- A **ColumnGroup** is nothing more than a list of **Columns** in a certain **ColumnGroupLayout**. For example: "one column taking up the entire width of the page", "two columns each taking up half of the width", ...
- Each **Column** can contain a number **ContentBlocks**
- Examples of a **ContentBlock** are: **TextBlock**, **NewsBlock**, **PictureBlock**, ...
- **ContentBlocks** can be given a certain sorting within a **Column**
- A **ContentBlock** can be put in different **Columns** so that content can be reused without having to be duplicated.

My first quick draft of how this could look like in C# code (we're using ASP.NET 4.0 to develop the CMS) can be found at the bottom of my question.

One of the technical requirements is that it must be as easy as possible to add new types of ContentBlocks to the CMS. So I would like model everything as flexible as possible. Unfortunately, I'm already stuck at trying to figure out how the database should look like.

One of the problems I'm having has to do with sorting different types of ContentBlocks in a Column. I guess each type of ContentBlock (like TextBlock, NewsBlock, PictureBlock, ...) should have it's own table in the database because each has it's own different fields. A TextBlock might only have a field called Text whereas a NewsBlock might have fields for the Text, the Summary, the PublicationDate, ...

Since one Column can have ContentBlocks located in different tables, I guess I'll have to create a many-to-many association for each type of ContentBlock. For example: ColumnTextBlocks, ColumnNewsBlocks and ColumnPictureBlocks.

The problem I have with this setup is the sorting of the different ContentBlocks in a column. This could be something like this:

1. TextBlock
2. NewsBlock
3. TextBlock
4. TextBlock
5. PictureBlock

Where do I store the sorting number? If I store them in the associaton tables, I'll have to update a lot of tables when changing the sorting order of ContentBlocks in a Column. Is this a good approach to the problem?

Basically, my question is: What is the best way to model this keeping in mind that it should be easy to add new types of ContentBlocks?

My next question is: What ORM can deal with that kind of modeling? To be honest, we are ORM-virgins at work. I have been reading a bit about Linq-to-SQL and NHibernate, but we have no experience with them. Because of the IList in the Column class (see code below) I think we can rule out Linq-to-SQL, right? Can NHibernate handle the mapping of data from many different tables to one IList?

Also keep in mind that this is just a very small portion of the domain. Other parts are **Users** belonging to a certain **UserGroup** having certain **Permissions** on **Pages**, **ColumnGroups**, **Columns** and **ContentBlocks**.

The code (just a quick first draft):

```
public class Page
{
    public int PageID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Keywords { get; set; }
    public IList<ColumnGroup> ColumnGroups { get; set; }
}

public class ColumnGroup
{
    public enum ColumnGroupLayout { OneColumn, HalfHalf, NarrowWide, WideNarrow }
    public int ColumnGroupID { get; set; }
    public ColumnGroupLayout Layout { get; set; }
    public IList<Column> Columns { get; set; }
}

public class Column
{
    public int ColumnID { get; set; }
    public IList<IContentBlock> ContentBlocks { get; set; }
}

public interface IContentBlock
{
    string GetSummary();
}

public class TextBlock : IContentBlock
{
    public string GetSummary()
    {
        return "I am a piece of text.";
    }
}

public class NewsBlock : IContentBlock
{
    public string GetSummary()
    {
        return "I am a news item.";
    }
}
```

Comment: "So I would like model everything as flexible as possible" You need to use the KISS principle http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Comment: @zaf: there are a lot of different interpretations of KISS. When our previous CTO told us to do it KISS, he actually meant "Don't use OO, just write the functionality you need, where you need it and when you need it. Just get the data you need, where you need it and when you need it. If that means that future changes take a long time and are difficult to implement, then so be it. That's a problem for the future. For now, we do it KISS" :-)

Comment: Is this for a website or a desktop application?

Comment: You really need to break up your question into several questions otherwise the only answer you're gonna get is to use microsoft access. If you catch my drift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not quite be what you're looking for but...

I find that using Microsoft Access is a quick way to create a functional database model (although limited) and to test out different query logic.

Using MS Access would then allow you to create your tables and then try out different iterations of how all the tables/data would link together quickly without needing to write lots of code.